# How to edit files with VIM through FTP

Tags: vim, ftp

I'm trying to use: `vim ftp://user@hostname//` - this gives me a correct directory tree, but when I try to open given file, by pressing Enter, at the first time - nothing happens (just cursor jumps to the "control" line at the bottom of the screen), when I'm pressing Enter again, I'm getting:

```
  1 ftp: username.hostname: Ta nazwa lub usługa jest nieznana // Rough translation: This name or service is not known
  2 Not connected.
  3 Not connected.
  4 Not connected.
```

I changed username and hostname above.

I want to edit file through FTP, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt to launch `vim` and then from within edit a file over FTP.

```
:e ftp://[user@]machine/path/
```

The plugin to `vim` that provides this feature is called `netrw`, it's included with `vim` by default. I'd take a look at the documentation specifically this section: [INTRODUCTION TO BROWSING](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-browse). It describes how to browse directories remotely through FTP.

Comment: I want to be able to browse files, so I tried this with only "/" instead of path, but I'm getting `Name (somehostname:mydesktoplogin): Login authentication failed
ftp: Login failed.` And I don't know why, as I'm adding in url correctusername@ O_o

Comment: @ŁukaszZaroda: It seems that your password for user is incorect. Did you try login normally via ftp?

Comment: This is the same password that was working when I was connecting from terminal. In fact, I'm just copying it from password manager in both cases so there is no possibility of typo.